# Can't use pip in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip

I want to use pip in Jupyter Notebook ,but there is a SyntaxError when i ran the code

```
pip install hyperopt
 File "<ipython-input-3-156c4fe098ed>", line 1
pip install hyperopt
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frs66.jpg)

Comment: It's a shell command, so you'll need to treat it like one by prefixing the command in Jupyter with a bang (`!pip install hyperopt`). Why not just install it outside the jupyter notebook, though?

Comment: it works,thank you!

Answer (score 8):

To run a shell command from within a notebook cell, you must put a `!` in front of the command:

```
!pip install hyperopt
```

Comment: If you explain why this is not a great idea, I'll give an upvote.

Comment: I get uesd to Jupyter Notebook